# mysql adding /dropping indexes and foreign key in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, foreign-keys

I have the following code:

```
alter table a 
add index a_idx1(a1,b1,c1),
add index a_idx2(d1),
add index b_idx(d3),
add constraint fk_1 foreign key(f1) references b(f2) on update restrict on delete restrict,
drop primary key,
add primary key(e2)
```

I initially had done it in separate steps, but to avoid locking issues etc, I did it in one, but it tends to sometimes degrade performance and weirdly sometimes bring down the database.

Is there anything in this statement that might do something to the db?

Comment: I do not understand the question. You sound like as if you regularly had to execute the above query.

Comment: I agree with Shadow -- adding indexes and FKs is _normally_ a one-time task.